# How do you find php.ini in ubuntu for phpv7.2

Tags: php

I have installed PHP v7.2. when I do `php -v` in my terminal, I get:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2017 20:14:31) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Which php, gives me, `/usr/bin/php`?

But there is no `php.ini` in that directory. How can I find the location of `php.ini`?

Comment: `locate php.ini` will search for it. Though you also will need to update it with `updatedb` once after installing (the database is not realtime to speed searching up by a lot).

Comment: $ updatedb
updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'

Comment: You need `sudo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cand find the `php.ini` file in the following directories:

- `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`
- `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where `7.0` is the version of PHP. You could include [these commands](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26312081/) with a little explanation, also the  Rinzwind's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991794/how-do-you-find-php-ini-in-ubuntu-for-phpv7-2#comment1599590_991794), in your answer to make it complete. :-)

Comment: This is for the apache installation. This is differnet from what you get by running php in the terminal

Comment: In that case, execute in your terminal `sudo updatedb` and then execute `locate php.ini` this will show the location of all `php.ini` files in your system.

Comment: @RamasamyViswanathan - look at the second bullet - `cli` means command-line-interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a file that calls the `phpinfo()` function. Simply add the following code into a file such as `phpinfo.php` in your webroot, and access it via the webserver.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

[image: Where is my PHP php.ini Configuration File Located]